# Sinch push samples not working on android 8.0 and higher when app is in background

Tags: android, sinch

i am implementing sinch in my project. I started testing sinch sample if its working. I found sinch push samples are not working on android 8.0 and higher and are working on lower versions. I tested my FCM implementation and is working fine but sinch push is not working when the app is not running.

Please help as i have tested all the solutions available on this site and none of the solutions worked.

```
public class SinchService extends Service {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "my app key here";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "my app secret here";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";

    public static final int MESSAGE_PERMISSIONS_NEEDED = 1;
    public static final String REQUIRED_PERMISSION = "REQUIRED_PESMISSION";
    public static final String MESSENGER = "MESSENGER";
    private Messenger messenger;

    public static final String CALL_ID = "CALL_ID";
    static final String TAG = SinchService.class.getSimpleName();

    private PersistedSettings mSettings;
    private SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient mSinchClient;

    private StartFailedListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mSettings = new PersistedSettings(getApplicationContext());
        attemptAutoStart();
    }

    private void attemptAutoStart() {
        String userName = mSettings.getUsername();
        if (!userName.isEmpty() && messenger != null) {
            start(userName);
        }
    }

    private void createClient(String username) {
        mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext()).userId(username)
                .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
                .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

        mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
        mSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);
        mSinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
        mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();

        mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
        mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted()) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void start(String username) {
        boolean permissionsGranted = true;
        if (mSinchClient == null) {
            mSettings.setUsername(username);
            createClient(username);
        }
        try {
            //mandatory checks
            mSinchClient.checkManifest();
        } catch (MissingPermissionException e) {
            permissionsGranted = false;
            if (messenger != null) {
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(REQUIRED_PERMISSION, e.getRequiredPermission());
                message.setData(bundle);
                message.what = MESSAGE_PERMISSIONS_NEEDED;
                try {
                    messenger.send(message);
                } catch (RemoteException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        if (permissionsGranted) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting SinchClient");
            mSinchClient.start();
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isStarted() {
        return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        messenger = intent.getParcelableExtra(MESSENGER);
        return mSinchServiceInterface;
    }

    public class SinchServiceInterface extends Binder {

        public Call callUser(String userId) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUser(userId);
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return mSinchClient != null ? mSinchClient.getLocalUserId() : "";
        }

        public void retryStartAfterPermissionGranted() { SinchService.this.attemptAutoStart(); }

        public boolean isStarted() {
            return SinchService.this.isStarted();
        }

        public void startClient(String userName) {
            start(userName);
        }

        public void stopClient() {
            stop();
        }

        public void setStartListener(StartFailedListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public Call getCall(String callId) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().getCall(callId);
        }

        public AudioController getAudioController() {
            if (!isStarted()) {
                return null;
            }
            return mSinchClient.getAudioController();
        }

        public NotificationResult relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(final Map payload) {
            if (mSinchClient == null && !mSettings.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
                createClient(mSettings.getUsername());
            } else if (mSinchClient == null && mSettings.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Can't start a SinchClient as no username is available, unable to relay push.");
                return null;
            }
            return mSinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(payload);
        }
    }

    public interface StartFailedListener {

        void onStartFailed(SinchError error);

        void onStarted();
    }

    private class MySinchClientListener implements SinchClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStartFailed(error);
            }
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient started");
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStarted();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
            switch (level) {
                case Log.DEBUG:
                    Log.d(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.ERROR:
                    Log.e(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.INFO:
                    Log.i(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.VERBOSE:
                    Log.v(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.WARN:
                    Log.w(area, message);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
                ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        }
    }
    private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onIncomingCall: " + call.getCallId());
            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


    private class PersistedSettings {

        private SharedPreferences mStore;

        private static final String PREF_KEY = "Sinch";

        public PersistedSettings(Context context) {
            mStore = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return mStore.getString("Username", "");
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mStore.edit();
            editor.putString("Username", username);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}


public class FcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private final String PREFERENCE_FILE = "com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.push.shared_preferences";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
        if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushPayload(data)) {
            new ServiceConnection() {
                private Map payload;

                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    if (payload != null) {
                        SinchService.SinchServiceInterface sinchService = (SinchService.SinchServiceInterface) service;
                        if (sinchService != null) {
                            NotificationResult result = sinchService.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(payload);
                            // handle result, e.g. show a notification or similar
                            // here is example for notifying user about missed/canceled call:
                            if (result.isValid() && result.isCall()) {
                                CallNotificationResult callResult = result.getCallResult();
                                if (callResult != null && result.getDisplayName() != null) {
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                    editor.putString(callResult.getRemoteUserId(), result.getDisplayName());
                                    editor.commit();
                                }
                                if (callResult.isCallCanceled()) {
                                    String displayName = result.getDisplayName();
                                    if (displayName == null) {
                                        displayName = sharedPreferences.getString(callResult.getRemoteUserId(),"n/a");
                                    }
                                    createNotification(displayName != null && !displayName.isEmpty() ? displayName : callResult.getRemoteUserId());
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                        context.deleteSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    payload = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {}

                public void relayMessageData(Map<String, String> data) {
                    payload = data;
                    getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SinchService.class), this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                }
            }.relayMessageData(data);
        }
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Sinch";
            String description = "Incoming Sinch Push Notifications.";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getResources().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private void createNotification(String userId) {

        createNotificationChannel();

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle("Missed call from:")
                        .setContentText(userId);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: @cjensen can you resolve this issue?